# Create intricate background gradient in CSS

Tags: html, css

Ignoring the basketball court in this image, we need to create a  with a background as similar as possible to the background behind this court:

- diagonal grey lines
- minor diagonal grey lines between the major diagonal grey lines
- small tick marks that are short diagonal lines perpendicular to the main diagonal lines. These short tick marks follow a fairly simple pattern.
- It is subtle but there is a box-shadow on the main diagonal grey lines, that becomes more and more noticeable as we move towards the bottom-right of the div.
- In general, the whole image becomes lighter as we move from bottom to top.

[image]

We don't have much yet, just this basic background with `repeating-linear-gradient`.

```css
.gradient {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    135deg,
    #DADADA,
    #DADADA 2px,
    white 2px,
    white 15px
  )
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">
  Close but not really all that close
</div>
```

We could theoretically draw this whole thing out with SVG lines, but that would challenging in-and-of-itself. A solution that gets the majority of the way there with CSS is preferred. Is this possible?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is a repeating image background, with a semi-transparent gradient overlay.

Comment: We are already seeing if we can get this as an image to use as a background image. However, there is a good chance we cannot get it as an image in time and will need to create this in CSS or JS instead.